# Determine dependency's greatest matching version that exists on an NPM server from a semver version

Tags: node.js, npm, semantic-versioning

I'm writing a node script which helps pin dependencies.

**How can I determine the greatest realized version of a package existing on an NPM server, from a semver version?**

For example, we have a dependency "foo" which is specified in a package.json as `~1.2.3`.
Out on NPM, there exists published version `1.2.5`, which is the latest published version compatible with `~1.2.3`.

I need to write a script that would take as input "foo" and `~1.2.3`, then after a server query, return `1.2.5`. Something like this:

```js
await fetchRealizedVersion('foo', '~1.2.3'); // resolves to 1.2.5
```

I understand I could do something like `yarn upgrade` and then parse the lock file, but I am looking for a more direct way of accomplishing this.
Hopefully there is a package that boils this down to an API call, but I'm not finding anything after googling around.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *"Hopefully there is a package that boils this down to an API call,"*

**Short Answer:** <strike>Unfortunately no, there is not a package that currently exists as far as I know.</strike>

*Edit:* There is the [`get-latest-version`](https://github.com/rexxars/get-latest-version) package you may want to try:

> **Basic usage:**
>
> ```js
> const getLatestVersion = require('get-latest-version')
>
> getLatestVersion('some-other-module', {range: '^1.0.0'})
>  .then((version) => console.log(version)) // highest version matching ^1.0.0 range
>  .catch((err) => console.error(err))
> ```

---

Alternatively, consider utilizing/writing a custom node.js module to perform the following steps:

1. Either:

   - Shell out the [npm view](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/view) command to retrieve all versions that are available in the NPM registry for a given package: For instance:

     ```
     npm view <pkg> versions --json
     ```
   - Or, directly make a `https` request to the public [npm registry](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/registry) at `https://registry.npmjs.org` to retrieve all versions available in for a given package.

2. Parse the JSON returned and pass it, along with the semver range (e.g. `~1.2.3`), to the [node-semver](https://github.com/npm/node-semver) package's `maxSatisfying()` method.

   The `maxSatisfying()` method is described in the [docs](https://github.com/npm/node-semver#ranges-1) as:

   > *`maxSatisfying(versions, range)`: Return the highest version in the list that satisfies the range, or `null` if none of them do.*

---

### Custom module (A):

The custom example module provided in `get-latest-version.js` (below) essentially performs the aforementioned steps. In this example we shell out the `npm view` command.

**get-latest-version.js**

```js
'use strict';

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Requirements
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

const { exec } = require('child_process');
const { maxSatisfying } = require('semver');

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Data
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

const errorBadge = '\x1b[31;40mERR!\x1b[0m';

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Helpers
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

/**
 * Captures the data written to stdout from a given shell command.
 *
 * @param {String} command The shell command to execute.
 * @return {Promise<string>} A Promise object whose fulfillment value holds the
 * data written to stdout. When rejected an error message is returned.
 * @private
 */
function shellExec(command) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    exec(command, (error, stdout, stderr) => {
      if (error) {
        reject(new Error(`Failed executing command: '${command}'`));
        return;
      }
      resolve(stdout.trim());
    });
  });
}

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Public Interface
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

module.exports = {

  /**
   * Retrieves the latest version that matches the given range for a package.
   *
   * @async
   * @param {String} pkg The package name.
   * @param {String} range The semver range.
   * @returns {Promise<string>} A Promise object that when fulfilled returns the
   * latest version that matches. When rejected an error message is returned.
   */
  async fetchRealizedVersion(pkg, range) {
    try {
      const response = await shellExec(`npm view ${pkg} versions --json`);
      const versions = JSON.parse(response);

      return maxSatisfying(versions, range);

    } catch ({ message: errorMssg }) {
      throw Error([
        `${errorBadge} ${errorMssg}`,
        `${errorBadge} '${pkg}' is probably not in the npm registry.`
      ].join('\n'));
    }
  }

};
```

---

### Usage:

The following `index.js` demonstrates using the aforementioned module.

**index.js**

```js
'use strict';

const { fetchRealizedVersion } = require('./get-latest-version.js');

(async function() {
  try {
    const latest = await fetchRealizedVersion('eslint', '~5.15.0');
    console.log(latest); // --> 5.15.3
  } catch ({ message: errMssg }) {
    console.error(errMssg);
  }
})();
```

As you can see, in that example we obtain the latest published version for the [eslint](https://github.com/eslint/eslint) package that is compatible with the semver tilde range `~5.15.0`.

The latest/maximum version that satisfies `~5.15.0` is printed to the console:

> ```
> $ node ./index.js
> 5.15.3
> ```

**Note:** You can always double check the results using the online [semver calculator](https://semver.npmjs.com/) which actually utilizes the `node-semver` package.

#### Another Usage Example:

The following `index.js` demonstrates using the aforementioned module to obtain the latest/maximum version for multiple packages and different ranges.

**index.js**

```js
'use strict';

const { fetchRealizedVersion } = require('./get-latest-version.js');

const criteria = [
  {
    pkg: 'eslint',
    range: '^4.9.0'
  },
  {
    pkg: 'eslint',
    range: '~5.0.0'
  },
  {
    pkg: 'lighthouse',
    range: '~1.0.0'
  },
  {
    pkg: 'lighthouse',
    range: '^1.0.4'
  },
  {
    pkg: 'yarn',
    range: '~1.3.0'
  },
  {
    pkg: 'yarn',
    range: '^1.3.0'
  },
  {
    pkg: 'yarn',
    range: '^20.3.0'
  },
  {
    pkg: 'quuxbarfoo',
    range: '~1.3.0'
  }
];


(async function () {

  // Each request is sent and read in parallel.
  const promises = criteria.map(async ({ pkg, range }) => {
    try {
      return await fetchRealizedVersion(pkg, range);
    } catch ({ message: errMssg }) {
      return errMssg;
    }
  });

  // Log each 'latest' semver in sequence.
  for (const latest of promises) {
    console.log(await latest);
  }
})();
```

The result for that last example is as follows:

> ```
> $ node ./index.js
> 4.19.1
> 5.0.1
> 1.0.6
> 1.6.5
> 1.3.2
> 1.22.4
> null
> ERR! Failed executing command: 'npm view quuxbarfoo versions --json'
> ERR! 'quuxbarfoo' is probably not in the npm registry.
> ```

---

<sub>**Additional Note:** The `shellExec` helper function in `get-latest-version.js` currently promisifies the `child_process` module's [`exec()`](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v12.x/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback) method to shell out the `npm view` command. However, since *node.js version 12* the built-in [`util.promisify`](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v12.x/api/util.html#util_util_promisify_original) provides another way to promisify the `exec()` method *(as shown in the docs for `exec`)*, so you may prefer to do it that way instead.</sub>

---

### Custom module (B):

If you wanted to avoid shelling out the `npm view` command you could consider making a request directly to the `https://registry.npmjs.org` endpoint instead (which is the same endpoint that the `npm view` command sends a https `GET` request to).

The modified version of `get-latest-version.js` (below) essentially utilizes a promisified version of the builtin [`https.get`](https://nodejs.org/api/https.html#https_https_get_options_callback).

Usage is the same as demonstrated previously in the *"Usage"* section.

**get-latest-version.js**

```js
'use strict';

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Requirements
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

const https = require('https');
const { maxSatisfying } = require('semver');

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Data
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

const endPoint = 'https://registry.npmjs.org';
const errorBadge = '\x1b[31;40mERR!\x1b[0m';

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Helpers
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

/**
 * Requests JSON for a given package from the npm registry.
 *
 * @param {String} pkg The package name.
 * @return {Promise<json>} A Promise object that when fulfilled returns the JSON
 * metadata for the specific package. When rejected an error message is returned.
 * @private
 */
function fetchPackageInfo(pkg) {

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

    https.get(`${endPoint}/${pkg}/`, response => {

      const { statusCode, headers: { 'content-type': contentType } } = response;

      if (statusCode !== 200) {
        reject(new Error(`Request to ${endPoint} failed. ${statusCode}`));
        return;
      }

      if (!/^application\/json/.test(contentType)) {
        reject(new Error(`Expected application/json but received ${contentType}`));
        return;
      }

      let data = '';

      response.on('data', chunk => {
        data += chunk;
      });

      response.on('end', () => {
        resolve(data);
      });

    }).on('error', error => {
      reject(new Error(`Cannot find ${endPoint}`));
    });
  });
}

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Public Interface
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

module.exports = {

  /**
   * Retrieves the latest version that matches the given range for a package.
   *
   * @async
   * @param {String} pkg The package name.
   * @param {String} range The semver range.
   * @returns {Promise<string>} A Promise object that when fulfilled returns the
   * latest version that matches. When rejected an error message is returned.
   */
  async fetchRealizedVersion(pkg, range) {
    try {
      const response = await fetchPackageInfo(pkg);
      const { versions: allVersionInfo } = JSON.parse(response);

      // The response includes all metadata for all versions of a package.
      // Let's create an Array holding just the `version` info.
      const versions = [];
      Object.keys(allVersionInfo).forEach(key => {
        versions.push(allVersionInfo[key].version)
      });

     return maxSatisfying(versions, range);

    } catch ({ message: errorMssg }) {
      throw Error([
        `${errorBadge} ${errorMssg}`,
        `${errorBadge} '${pkg}' is probably not in the npm registry.`
      ].join('\n'));
    }
  }

};
```

---

<sub>**Note** The version of [node-semver](https://github.com/npm/node-semver) used in the example custom modules (A & B) IS NOT the current latest version (i.e. `7.3.2`). Version `^5.7.1` was used instead - which is the same version used by the [npm cli](https://github.com/npm/cli/blob/42e46256156eb6446862f208896d844acf3b8c5d/package.json#L130) tool.</sub>

---

Comment: You may also be interested in [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58773187/how-can-i-get-the-exact-latest-npm-version-from-a-relative-version/58791199#58791199). It's not a _node.js_ solution, however it describes how this can be achieved directly via the command line by providing a semver to the `npm view` command and parsing the results.