# NPM Version History API

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I was trying to build something like [Bundlephobia](https://cost-of-modules.herokuapp.com/). I am trying to get version history of npm packages. Is there any API service available like `npm view [packagename] versions --json`. I want to get the version history e.g version names and release dates of every previous versions

Comment: Note that if you run `npm --verbose ...` you can see what API requests are being made by the commands you're running, then you can make your own requests to see what other data comes back.

Comment: Great. In that case, should I write like `npm --verbose npm view {packagename} --json`?

Comment: That will show you what endpoints are getting hit by the view command, yes.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't spot that you'd written `npm` twice. `npm --verbose view ...`. In general, please don't post screenshots of text content on SO.

Comment: Running `npm view <package_name> time --json` will retrieve all versions and the published date for a given package.

Comment: Or via node.js utilize [`https.get()`](https://nodejs.org/api/https.html#https_https_get_options_callback) to send a request to the [npm registry](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/registry) endpoint: `https://registry.npmjs.org/<pkg_name>`, whereby the `<pkg_name>` should be replace with the name of the package. Then parse the JSON response and obtain the value of the `"time": { .... }` property. For example: [https://registry.npmjs.org/eslint](https://registry.npmjs.org/eslint) is the JSON metadata for the `eslint` package.

Comment: The `fetchPackageInfo` function shown in the section titled _"Custom module (B)"_ of my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63022138/determine-dependencys-greatest-matching-version-that-exists-on-an-npm-server-fr/63033062#63033062) demonstrates how to requests JSON for a given package from the npm registry.

Comment: ow thanks. These suggestions were very useful. One last thing I wanted to know. When I `fetchPackageInfo` it shows me all the versions including the experimental and majors too. Is there any way to distinguish major versions from experimental of non major versions?

Comment: @Arnab - Experimental versions include a hyphen (`-`) and stable versions do not. Consider utilizing [`Array.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) with [`String.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes) to obtain either stable or experimental versions only. Let's assume `versions` is an array of all semvers, you can do:  `const experimentalVersions = versions.filter(v => v.includes('-'))` and/or `const stableVersions = versions.filter(v => !v.includes('-'))`