# Is there an option that can show me what semantic versions of a particular npm package will resolve to?

Tags: node.js, npm, semantic-versioning

For instance, say I have "foo: ^1.0.0" listed in my package.json and that project's released versions are [1.0.0, 1.1.0, 1.2.0, 2.0.0]. I want to find out what ^1.0.0 resolves to **without** installing or looking it up manually. Does a tool for this exist? I would expect it to be something like `npm resolve foo@^1.0.0`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I get the exact latest npm version from a relative version?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58773187/how-can-i-get-the-exact-latest-npm-version-from-a-relative-version)

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is!

If you're using npm use [view](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/commands/npm-view)

```
npm view foo@^1.0.0
```

Otherwise you could use `yarn` with [info](https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/info)

```
yarn info foo@^1.0.0
```

And in case you want even better statistics check out [bundlephobia](https://bundlephobia.com/). It gives size estimations for the given version as well as the others and also an analysis of the exports.