# Is there a npm registry query to get the package with to get minor or patch version package details

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-package, npm-registry

can anyone help me with query to get a package with minor or patch versions from npm registry.

https://registry.npmjs.org/eslint-scope/7.1.1 - this would give package details for 7.1.1 version.
I would like to understand how can we pass ^7.1.1 or ~7.1.1(not 7.1.1) to get minor or patch versions above 7.1.1 if available.

Thanks.

Comment: Consider utilising the solution provided in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63022138/determine-dependencys-greatest-matching-version-that-exists-on-an-npm-server-fr/63033062#63033062) to determine the version before sending the appropriate query.

Comment: ... or determine the version using the solution provided in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58773187/how-can-i-get-the-exact-latest-npm-version-from-a-relative-version/58791199#58791199).

Comment: I would rather like to do it using API instead of using registry package.